# Urn model and recursion

Tags: pr.probability, recurrences, difference-equations

We have an urn with $n$ white balls. In each iteration we pick a ball at random. If it's white, we paint it red and return it to the urn. If it's already red, we discard it. We lose the game if (after the first iteration and before emptying the urn) we get zero red balls, otherwise we win.

We want to compute the probability of success $p(n)$, and its asympotics when $n \to \infty$.

It's easy to get the recursion

$$P_{i,j} = \frac{i}{i+j} P_{i-1,j}+ \frac{j}{i+j} P_{i+1,j-1} \tag 1$$

where $P_{i,j}$ is the probability of success given that we have $j$ white balls and $i$ red balls (and the failure event has not happened), with the boundary conditions $P_{0,j}=0$ for $j>0$ and $P_{i,0}=1$. We want $p(n)=P_{1,n-1}$.

In this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828875/312) I conjectured a semi empirical asymptotics $$p(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{\log n} + o(\log^{-1} n)\tag 2$$

or, hopefully more precise

$$p(n) \approx \left(1- \frac{1}{h(n)}\right)\left(1- \frac{1}{n}\right) \tag 3$$

where $h(n)=-W_{-1}(-1/n)=\log(n)+\log(\log n + \log \log \cdots)$ is the (greatest) solution of $e^h= n h $

Questions:

- Does the recursion $(1)$, and hence $p(n)$, has some closed form solution?
- Can the asymptotics $(2)$ or $(3)$ can be confirmed and better justified?
- Is there some references about this kind of problem?

Comment: Why does the first iteration rule matter? If $P_{0,j} = 0$ then the implication is given an urn with $j$ white balls to start regardless how one of them changes color on the first move we already have lost. So the “first iteration” condition should be removed OR the boundary $P_{0,j} = 0$ should be removed I think

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal The interpretation given of $P_{i,j}$ is valid for $i,j\ge 1$. The boundary conditions (outside that range) are set so to agree with the rules of the game. For example $P_{3,1}= \frac{3}{4} P_{2,1} + \frac{1}{4} 0$

Comment: Yes but instead you could just say “the rules of the game are if you have 0 red balls at any time you lose. If you have a non zero number of red balls. Select a ball, if it’s red, then discard it, if it’s white it becomes red and goes back in”. Then $P_{0,j}=0$ isn’t an external condition it’s built into the rules of the game and “first iteration” part of your rules can be removed. Anyway this is minutia, I don’t think this changes your question.